# Get the amount of an item in the DataBase

Tags: java

im learning by my own and making a little Selling system... 
I have a method who (in theory) gives me the amount of "X" item in a DataBase.

I tryied in different ways but i cant get it work.

```
    public int cantidadVenta (Bebidas vo){
 int cantidadVenta = vo.getCantidadCarrito();

 DBCon conec = new DBCon();
    String sql = "SELECT cantidad FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ? ";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
     try {
            ps = conec.Connect().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, vo.getCantidadCarrito());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            cantidadVenta= vo.getCantidadCarrito();

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, "Error en consulta", e);
        }

 //System.out.println("DAO variable CantidadVenta en VENTAS HOY es: "+cantidadVenta);
 return cantidadVenta;
}
```

I tryed giving another parameter as an String product... How can i do to get the number of an item in my DB?

Thanks!

Btw:  Sorry my english!!  (Is something im learning by myself too)

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the results. You just leave your `ResultSet` there and do `cantidadVenta= vo.getCantidadCarrito();` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SQL aggregation function like `COUNT`,  change

```
SELECT cantidad FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ?
```

to

```
SELECT COUNT(cantidad) FROM VENTAS_HOY WHERE producto = ?
```

And then use `rs.getInt(1)` to get that `COUNT`.

Comment: How can i retireve that rs.getInt(1) into a int or something i cant return in the method?  Thanks!

Comment: `int v = rs.getInt(1);` and `return v;` or `return rs.getInt(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate functions and change your SQL string to use the `COUNT` function of SQL.